# Any tidier ways of removing extensive white space from user input?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a method that removes extensive white space from user input, so that it does not mess up the formatting of information being presented through a UI or report.  I want the user to be prevented from using tabs, multiple spaces and more than two carriage returns in a row. Here's my current solution (which works perfectly), but does anyone have anything tidier?  My main challenge was making sure the user could use either single or double carriage returns:

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    private static readonly string SingleBreakGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    private static readonly string DoubleBreakGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    /// <summary>
    /// Limits character spacing to single spacing.  Limits line spacing to no more than double line spacing. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceString">The source string that will be used to calculate the result.</param>
    /// <returns>A string with single spacing between characters and no more than double line spacing.</returns>
    public static string RemoveExtensiveWhiteSpace(this string sourceString)
    {
        // Normalise breaks, so that they are all \r\n
        var normalisedString = sourceString.NormaliseLineBreaks();

        // Replace multiple spaces and tabs with a single space
        var singleSpacedString = string.Join(" ", normalisedString.Split(new[] { " ", "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        // Trim all of the sub-strings between breaks - this will also empty any whitespace between breaks
        var trimmedString = string.Join("\r\n",
            singleSpacedString.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(s => s.Trim()));

        // The logic requires that the user can use one or two carriage returns, which difficult to achieve by splitting and re-joining.
        // Replace the double and single carriage returns with respective Guids
        var guidNotationString = trimmedString.Replace("\r\n\r\n", DoubleBreakGuid).Replace("\r\n", SingleBreakGuid);

        // Merge trailing DoubleBreakGuid with trailing SingleBreakGuid into just a DoubleBreakGuid.
        var includesTripleBreaks = guidNotationString.Replace(DoubleBreakGuid + SingleBreakGuid, DoubleBreakGuid);

        // Replace groups of DoubleBreakGuid with a double break
        var includesDoubleBreaks = string.Join("\r\n\r\n",
            includesTripleBreaks.Split(new[] { DoubleBreakGuid }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        // Replace groups of SingleBreakGuid with single breaks
        var includesSingleBreaks = string.Join("\r\n",
            includesDoubleBreaks.Split(new[] { SingleBreakGuid }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        return includesSingleBreaks;
    }

    public static string NormaliseLineBreaks(this string sourceString)
    {
        return sourceString
            .Replace("\r\n", "\n")
            .Replace("\n\r", "\n")
            .Replace("\r", "\n")
            .Replace("\n", "\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works I'd leave it as it is (maybe clean up some redundant code - the last couple of lines don't look very efficient)  but if you are looking for something shorter, you could give Regex a try or use a StringBuilder to rebuild the string **once** instead of Replacing/Splitting/Joining it multiple times.

Comment: This question serves more purpose on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this isn't written good, there are many points to improve performance

Comment: @S.Serp Thank you for your comments.  Do you have an example of the code refactored?  Thanks

Comment: pleas check my answers (and provide your comments), to Phil and @ManfredRadlwimmer

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterative method to reduce multiple line breaks down to just a double line break. Rather than the weird guid substitution, use something like:

```
var collapsedString = trimmedString.Replace("\r\n\r\n\r\n","\r\n\r\n");
while(collapsedString.Length < trimmedString.Length)
{
  trimmedString = collapsedString;
  collapsedString = trimmedString.Replace("\r\n\r\n\r\n","\r\n\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  I'll have a go at this and come back.

Comment: i think there is a simpler method to do so, please see [my second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42745271/2803565) for reduce multiple line breaks to a double line breaks

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains many many replaces..., and each replace needs to iterate whole input string and create a new string based on match criteria.

Here i wrote a code that loop only once and skip repetitive white space (`' ' , '\t'`) and line break chars (`'\r', '\n', '\r\n', '\n\r'`) as you want:

It must be noted that if we had a known line-break char, the code could be simpler. but i didn't use that `NormaliseLineBreaks` func in your code here.

```
public static class StringHelper
{

    public static string RemoveExtraWhiteSpace(this string s)
    {
        int n = s.Length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n); //to make output
        int nLineBreaks = 2; //number of repetitive line breaks, assume there were 2 enter chars before begining of s (to avoid adding initial line breaks or spaces)
        bool prevCharWasCrLf = false; //we can't use nEneter for this purpose as it skip white spaces between line breaks
        char ch1, ch = '\0'; //ch1 is prev char, ch is current char

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //iterate through chars
        {
            ch1 = ch; ch = s[i]; //get next char

            if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n')
            {
                if (prevCharWasCrLf && ch != ch1) { prevCharWasCrLf = false; continue; } //this char is second of CrLf pair, ignore it as we already treat it
                //if (prevCharWasCrLf == false || ch == ch1) /if we prefer don't use continue
                prevCharWasCrLf = true;
                nLineBreaks++;
                if (nLineBreaks <= 2) //append new line break if we have less than 2 
                {
                    if (sb.Length > 0 && sb[sb.Length - 1] == ' ') sb.Length--;  //remove prev space as it was before an enter
                    sb.Append("\r\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t')
                {
                    if (nLineBreaks == 0 && ch1 != ' ' && ch1 != '\t') sb.Append(' '); //don't add more space after another space or enter
                }
                else
                {
                    nLineBreaks = 0; sb.Append(ch); //its a normal char, add it to output
                }
                prevCharWasCrLf = false;
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString().TrimEnd('\r', '\n'); //if we don't use nReturn = 2 at begining, we shall run: .Trim('\r', '\n', ' ', '\t');
    }
}
```

It may require some fine-tuning, but it works in my tests...

Also, i know it is not a short code, but in my opinion, its cleaner and most important: it has very better performance!

Answer (score 0):

If you care the performance try my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42718018/2803565), but if you are looking for a shorter and easy to follow code, this can be your answer:

```
public string RemoveExtensiveWhiteSpace(string s)
{
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r", "\r\n"); //normalize all type of line breaks to \r\n
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[ \t]+", " "); // \t+|[\t ]{2,}
    s = s.Replace("\r\n ", "\r\n").Replace(" \r\n", "\r\n"); //Regex.Replace(s, @"(\r\n | \n\r)", "\r\n")
    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\r\n){2,}", "\r\n\r\n"); //replace 2+ new line breaks with 2
    return s.Trim('\r', '\n', ' '); //remove initial & final white space chars
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, I haven't had a chance to try it out yet as have been pulled onto something pressing, but I will get back about it.

Comment: did you check this? i think this could be the short way as you asked